# ANTLR: error recovery and reporting

Tags: java, antlr

i have problems to recovery and reposting error with ANTLR v3. i follow this link http://www.antlr.org/blog/antlr3/error.handling.tml but i don't have that solutions.
i want to make some reporting and recovery
for example in the source program like this :
student input code :

```
FOR(int a=0;a<10;a++){
 b=b*a;
}
```

and the program will report like this:
Program : "are you meant the keyword FOR is for?"
student answer:"yes"
after that, the system recovery and modified the source code automatically.
How to do like that with ANTLR v3?imposible to do with ANTLR?
need help. thanks guys!

Comment: Is restarting the parse from scratch acceptable? It might simplify the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override `org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken` inside your generated parser class.

This function is called when ANTLR detects an invalid token. So in your own function you can asks the user whether recovery is needed.

If needed, then you can call `BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken` to perform the recovery. If not, you can throw an exception `MismatchedTokenException`.

Comment: can you give me the link for that example?i just confuse. but thanks before lex li

Comment: I cannot give you a Java example, as I use ANTLR in C#. https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/2f9e8d2d48547b37e7cb6d75cdcb0ffae29f82e3/SharpSnmpLib/Mib/SmiParser.cs This is a partial class defined in C#, which will be finally merged with the ANTLR generated SmiParser.cs file from Smi.g grammar file. SmiParser class is derived from ANTLR's BaseRecognizer. Here I override RecoverFromMismatchedToken function to simply throw an exception all the times. In Java you should use a similar way to override the function and then implement your own logic.

Comment: thanks lex li for that solution. for your case, that imposible to used the concept of ANTLR like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262195/parsing-java-code-with-antlr-need-concept

Comment: @Berto: I think the `recoverFromMismatchedToken` will happen _before_ the AST is generated. You ought to be able to use the AST even with this approach.